# Writing a shader that creates an outline around a pixel sprite in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing an iOS app and thought it would be a good idea to write a shader that creates a green outline around selected sprites. I'm very new to shaders and have run into problems. Because custom shaders overwrite default behavior like filtering mode on SKSpriteNodes, my sprites become blurry and the outline is not touching the image, because of the semi-transparent transition pixels from the image border to the transparent background.

What I want is to create an outline (every transparent pixel that is touching a non-transparent pixel should become green) without removing the default behavior provided by SKDefaultShading().

My swift code:

```
// "spriteNamed" init automaticly sets filtermode to .nearest
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(spriteNamed: "chair_east")
let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "selectedShader.fsh")

shader.attributes = [
    SKAttribute(name: "a_sprite_size", type: .vectorFloat2)
]

sprite.shader = shader

// The sprite's dimensions are 40x60, but it does not normally     
//  fill out that space.
let spriteSize = vector_float2(Float(40), Float(60))
sprite.setValue(SKAttributeValue(vectorFloat2: spriteSize),
                forAttribute: "a_sprite_size")

addChild(sprite)
```

My selectedShader.fsh code:

```
void main() {
    vec4 current_color = texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);
    vec2 pixel = vec2(1.0/a_sprite_size.x, 1.0/a_sprite_size.y);

    vec4 color1 = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_tex_coord.x+pixel.x, v_tex_coord.y));
    vec4 color2 = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_tex_coord.x-pixel.x, v_tex_coord.y));
    vec4 color3 = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_tex_coord.x, v_tex_coord.y+pixel.y));
    vec4 color4 = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_tex_coord.x, v_tex_coord.y-pixel.y));

    vec4 selectionColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    //if (current_color.a == 0.0) {
    if (SKDefaultShading().a == 0.0) {
        if (color1.a > 0.0) {
            gl_FragColor = selectionColor;
        } else if (color2.a > 0.0) {
            gl_FragColor = selectionColor;
        } else if (color3.a > 0.0) {
            gl_FragColor = selectionColor;
        } else if (color4.a > 0.0) {
            gl_FragColor = selectionColor;
        } else {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = SKDefaultShading();
    }
}
```

If the above code can be improved by a loop (can you even write loops in OpenGL?) or such, please tell me :D

Here is a picture! Left is pre shader, right is post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIcLg.png

Comment: If you have semi transparent pixels then you are going to need to increase your alpha threshold from >0,  or use a mask for your graphics and have the shader work with the mask

Comment: @KnigtOfDragon I don't, in the original texture at least. The issue lies in the fact that when the texture is getting scaled, it's scaled linearly which create these semi-transparent pixels.